# jQuery functions not working in IE or on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, ios, internet-explorer

Several of my jQuery functions aren't working in IE or on my iOS device. I don't have an Android so I don't know about that.

### Function One:

```
function keepGoing(anchor, id, scrollSpeed = 1000 ) {
    $(anchor).css("cursor","pointer");
    $(anchor).click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
        }, scrollSpeed );
    });
}
```

### Function Two:

```
function showOnScroll(targetClass,cssAttr,attrValue) {
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {

      $(targetClass).each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
          el.css(cssAttr,attrValue); 
        } 
      });

    });
}
showOnScroll('.fast-track-img','margin-left','unset');
showOnScroll('.own-speed-img','margin-left','unset');
showOnScroll('.rising-star-img','margin-left','unset');
```

Comment: please update your question to make it relatable to other people searches. currently this question is very vague with not a specific part of error explained in the question

Comment: @Shubhank I have updated my question. Can you let me know if it is better now and if there is anything else I could do to improve the question. I also edited my answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem One: function parameters default set

Function parameter defaults is very new syntax only added in ECMAScript 2015.
Use something like this instead:

```
function(param) {
  if (param === undefined) param = val;
    // ...
}
```

### Problem Two:

The second problem was IE and the mobile browsers don't like `margin:unset;` but prefer `margin:0;`